# How to create Makefile in Python

Tags: python, makefile

I have never made a Makefile for Python before and I am struggling to figure it out. I found some sample code online and tried to apply it to my code but it is not working. If I wanted to run the program in command line I would do this: `python cryptBreak.py encrypted.txt plain.txt`.

Here is what I got for the Makefile so far:

```
PY=python2
MAIN=main
DIR=$(PWD)
.SUFFIXES: .py
FILES = \
    cryptBreak.py encrypted.txt  plain.txt
All: 
        echo " $(PY) $(DIR)/$(FILES) " \"'$$1'\" > cryptBreak 
        chmod 777 cryptBreak.py
```

Comment: You don't need to have a makefile in order to run python code.

Comment: @Dschoni I am aware of that but I am required too.

Comment: Does this help? https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/makefiles-in-python-projects.html

Comment: What is the makefile supposed to do?

Comment: @Dschoni yes thank you!

Comment: The link has died but here here is an archived version for anyone else interested in the link provided by @Dschoni: [https://web.archive.org/web/20220705051319/https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/makefiles-in-python-projects/](https://web.archive.org/web/20220705051319/https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/makefiles-in-python-projects/)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't explained why you need a makefile.  But if you just want to have a makefile that will run the command you listed, you just have to put the command in a recipe.  There's no need for all that other stuff.

```
all:
        python cryptBreak.py encrypted.txt plain.txt
```

That's it.  Now, in your makefile you seem to show that want to run `python2`, not `python`.  If you want to do that and make a variable to hold it then you can use:

```
PY := python2

all:
        $(PY) cryptBreak.py encrypted.txt plain.txt
```

If you need your makefile to do other things or have other requirements, we can't help if you don't specify them in your question.